# Copy only Employee id to excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I have a unformatted data containing in Notepad file as shown below.

```
#Civil
GROUP CIVIL RPatel66 LKohli12 m12 PSen72 m72
GROUP CIVIL SKumar22 ASekar32 m32 BSiva90 
#Mechanical
GROUP MECHANICAL OKhan78 m78 MShah81 JKumar11 
GROUP MECHANICAL VHiremath12 TVasu43 m43 NReddy21
#Electrical
GROUP ELECTRICAL LPathan88 SPatil56 m56 AParth33
GROUP ELECTRICAL HAnil45 m45 Khari67 m67 Skumar49
```

When i run the below code

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
f = open('C:\\Users\\Kiran\\Desktop\\Input.txt', 'r+') 
data = f.readlines()
spaces = ""
for i in range(len(data)):
    row = data[i].split(" ")  
    ws.append(row)
wb.save("Output1.xlsx")

import openpyxl
book= openpyxl.load_workbook('Output1.xlsx')
sheet = book['Sheet']
sheet.delete_cols(1,2) #deletes Column 1 and 2
book.save("Output1.xlsx")
```

For the above i am getting error and not getting the required output as i need.

I need output in a excel sheet as shown below.I need output as Eg:Rpatel66,LKohli12 etc in the excel sheet it should not contain m12,m72

```
RPatel66
LKohli12
PSen72
SKumar22 
ASekar32
BSiva90
OKhan78
MShah81
JKumar11
VHiremath12
TVasu43
NReddy21
LPathan88
SPatil56
AParth33
HAnil45
Khari67
Skumar49
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: all `m12`, `m72` starts with `m` and have length `3` - so use it to filter values in `row` before you put in excel. But it seems you do nothing to filter it, What did you try to remove `m12`?

Comment: Actually in the output excel i do not need m12,m72,m32,m78,m43,m56,m45,m67. I do not need the those things. For any given text file i need only "Eg: Skumar49"

Comment: then remove `m12,m72,m32,m78,m43,m56,m45,m67` from `row` before you use `ws.append(row)`. But in your code you don't even try to do this.

Comment: ie. `row = [x for x in row if not (len(x) == 3 and x[0] == 'm')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the below code to get the desired output for your query. Assuming the data is present in **<your-file-name.txt>**

```
import re
import pandas as pd
with open("<your-file-name.txt>",'r') as f:
    content=f.readlines()
    
content = [x for x in content if not x.startswith('#')]
temp_content_1=list(map(lambda x: x.replace('GROUP','').replace('MECHANICAL','').replace('CIVIL','').replace('ELECTRICAL','').strip(), content))

temp_content_2=list(map(lambda x: re.sub(' m\d+','',x), temp_content_1))

final=' '.join(temp_content_2).split()
df=pd.DataFrame({"Employee":final})
df.to_excel("<your-output-file-name.xlsx>", index=None)
```

**Alternate Solution**

```
import re
import pandas as pd
with open("<your-file-name.txt>",'r') as f:
    content=f.readlines()

temp_content_1=list(map(lambda x: re.sub(' m\d+','',x), content))
temp_content_2=' '.join(temp_content_1)

final=re.findall(r'\w+\d+', temp_content_2)    
df=pd.DataFrame({"Employee":final})
df.to_excel("<your-output-file-name.xlsx>", index=None)
```

Comment: THis code works for this case, But i have other few text files. There the data is diffrent it does not contain CIVIL ELECTRICAL MECHANICAL. So is there a way in Python where in for a given Text file i need output as shown above.

Comment: You can add the other keywords and preprocess/cleanse it. There is no automated way where you can get the employee ids without cleansing the text data first.

Comment: I've edited the solution with an alternate, using only regex but it assumes that employee keyword is a combination of word & digit

Comment: Please mark it as **Answered** if it serves your purpose.